# EntityManager doesn't update data in @ManyToMany relation field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm using JPA of ORM Hibernate and have next DAO class:

```
public class CarsOrm  {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "springHibernate", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public boolean addCar(Car car) {
        if (em.find(Car.class, car.regNumber) != null)
            return false;
        Model model = em.find(Model.class, car.modelName);
        if (model == null)
            return false;
        em.persist(car);
        return true;

    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean addOwner(Owner owner) {
        if (em.find(Owner.class, owner.id) != null)
            return false;
        em.persist(owner);
        return true;

    }


    public Iterable<Owner> getOwners(long regNumber) {
        Car car = em.find(Car.class, regNumber);
        return car==null?null:car.getOwners();
    }

   ...
}
```

Entities are next:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {
    @Id
    long regNumber;
    String color;
    @ManyToOne
    Model model;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Owner> owners;
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner {
    @Id
    int id;
    String ownerName;
    int yearBirth;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "owners", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Car> cars;
...
}
```

I'm doing next steps:

1. Create owner object: `Owner owner = new Owner(1000000, "Petro", 1976);` (owner.cars == null ) and save it using CarsOrm.addOwner()
2. Create car object:

   Integer[] owners = {owner};
   Car car = new Car(9999999, "Black", owners, model.getModelName());

(car.owners filled) and save it Using CarsOrm.addCar()

When after tat I'm using CarsOrm.getOwners(long regNumber) it return null.
Orm don't make request to database - it takes object from cash that was saved on step 1 with owner.cars == null. If I reboot program when objects are persisted the function works correct - retrieve correct set of owners. 
Why object **owner** don't updates in cashe after another object - **car** persisting and changing it's set of cars?

Answer (score -2):

You could try to add `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` to your @ManyToMany annotation.

But I recomment not to rely on hibernate. You should add the car to owner in the consturctor of Car. This is helpfull if you do some additional checks before persisting the entity e.g. in JUnit Tests.

```
public Car(long regNumber, String color, Owner owner, Model model){
  ...
  owner.addCar(this);
}
```